# How do I exit a foreach loop in C#?

Tags: c#, foreach

```
foreach (var name in parent.names)
{
    if name.lastname == null)
    {
        Violated = true;
        this.message = "lastname reqd";
    }

    if (!Violated)
    {
        Violated = !(name.firstname == null) ? false : true;
        if (ruleViolated)
            this.message = "firstname reqd";
    }
}
```

Whenever violated is true, I want to get out of the `foreach` loop immediately. How do I do it?

Answer (score 245):

Use [`break`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/adbctzc4.aspx).

---

Unrelated to your question, I see in your code the line:

```
Violated = !(name.firstname == null) ? false : true;
```

In this line, you take a boolean value `(name.firstname == null)`. Then, you apply the `!` operator to it. Then, if the value is true, you set Violated to false; otherwise to true. So basically, Violated is set to the same value as the original expression `(name.firstname == null)`. Why not use that, as in:

```
Violated = (name.firstname == null);
```

Comment: I don't like to see needless if tests and negation.

Answer (score 167):

Just use the statement:

```
break;
```

Answer (score 42):

Use the [`break`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/adbctzc4.aspx) keyword.

Answer (score 20):

Look at this code, it can help you to get out of the loop fast!

```
foreach (var name in parent.names)
{
   if (name.lastname == null)
   {
      Violated = true;
      this.message = "lastname reqd";
      break;
   }
   else if (name.firstname == null)
   {
      Violated = true;
      this.message = "firstname reqd";
      break;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 11):

`break;` - to exit foreach

`continue;` - jump to next value

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `foreach` loop

```
foreach (var name in parent.names)
{
    if name.lastname == null)
    {
        Violated = true;
        this.message = "lastname reqd";
    }

    if (!Violated)
    {
        Violated = !(name.firstname == null) ? false : true;
        if (ruleViolated)
            this.message = "firstname reqd";
    }
}
```

make use of equivalent `for` loop

```
bool Violated = false;

for (int i = 0; i < parent.names.Count && !Violated; i++)
{
    var name = parent.names[i];
    
    if (name.lastname == null)
    {
        Violated = true;
        this.message = "lastname reqd";
    }

    if (!Violated)
    {
        Violated = name.firstname == null;
        if (ruleViolated)
            this.message = "firstname reqd";
    }
}
```

With the condition `i < parent.names.Count && !Violated` you get full control to stop the loop safe without any `break` or `return` or whatever to brutally force the `foreach` to stop.

Sidenotes

- I changed `Violated = !(name.firstname == null) ? false : true;` to equivalent expression `Violated = name.firstname == null;`.
- I guess `ruleViolated` is different to `Violated`.

Comment: Unnecessarily making the code complex.

Comment: @AbhishekDutt: Hello, where is the complexity for you? Is it because of using for instead foreach? Or not using break?

Answer (score -1):

During testing I found that foreach loop after break go to the loop beging and not out of the loop. So I changed foreach into for and break in this case work correctly- after break program flow goes out of the loop.

Comment: The MS docs say `break` goes out and in my code it does as well https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/foreach-in
`continue` goes to the next iteration.