# break the foreach loop without completion

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Exiting Foreach loop in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/456276/exiting-foreach-loop-in-c-sharp)

I need to compare two registry key i.e HKEY_USER and  HKEY_CURRENT_USER.

```
I am using two methods..both are having foreach loops..
```

The first method calls another method which also having foreach loop. After performing required operation the condition should go to the first loop which is in the first method and also where the condition goes to the next loop..

Simply, breaking the inner loop and maintaining the outer loop.

I want to break the inner loop after executing the specific method..

```
        string[] mainkeys1 = mckey.GetSubKeyNames();

        foreach (string skey1 in mainkeys1)
         {
          ckey = skey1;

           mckey = l1.OpenSubKey(_ckey);

           int mcnt2 = mckey.SubKeyCount;

           if (mcnt2 > 0)
            {
             Getvaluescur();
             RegistryKey l2 = mckey;

             string[] mainkeys2 = mckey.GetSubKeyNames();

                            foreach (string skey2 in mainkeys2)
                            {
                                ckey = skey2;

                                mckey = l2.OpenSubKey(_ckey);

                                int mcnt3 = _mckey.SubKeyCount;

                                if (mcnt3 > 0)
                                  ....
                                  ....
```

The above code is also inside the Foreach loop..
I want to break the loop after executing the required methods..

Can anyone guide me to break the Foreach loop without completion..

Thank you..

Comment: Can you provide a simpler example of what you mean?  I'm having trouble understanding your question.

Comment: Have you tried using `break`? Also, consider converting your loop into a vanilla `while` or `for` and using the looping condition to break out of the loop.

Comment: @SteveDog.. Sir I have to compare Two registry key values like HKEY_USER and HKEY_CURRENT_USER. For this purpose i am using two method for finding the subkeys of each mainkey. I have to compare the values of each and every subkey.. Is any easy way to compare the Windows registry keys.??

Answer (score 3):

Just add a [`break;`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/adbctzc4%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) where you want to end the loop before completion.

Comment: You can quote the msdn article too: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/adbctzc4%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Comment: Thank you for your replies..

If i use break, it will cause the anbother problem like when the the codition flow from the initial it will automatically skip the statemens. I want break only after executing the methods in the loop.

Answer (score 2):

`break;` keyword is used to break the loop in programming.

and `continue;` keyword is used to break the loop and let the loop continue loop again.

please refer,

break:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/adbctzc4(v=vs.80).aspx and,

continue:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/923ahwt1(v=vs.71).aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/923ahwt1.aspx

Comment: If i use break, it will cause the anbother problem like when the the codition flow from the initial it will automatically skip the statemens. I want break only after executing the methods in the loop.

Comment: The loop may execute more times for next iteration..If i put break, the next iteration will affect before executing the required statements.

Comment: if you wish to break current flow and continue loop again, then use `continue` keyword, see my edited answer

Comment: No..I want to break the loop only.. Shortly i want to compare the values of HKEY_USER and H_KEY_CURRENT_USER 
For this purpose, I have two method to find all the subkeys of each key. To find several keys i use foreach loop..First i set uservalue1..then have to check whether the value and keyname is matched with the default value in HKEY_USER. My problem is the first value is checked with all the subkeys in 2nd key.. I want to break the second loop after finding the name and value that is matched with the first name and value.

Answer (score 0):

Use the intruction [`break`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/adbctzc4%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) to stop the loop execution when some specific condtion is met

```
foreach (string skey2 in mainkeys2)
{
   ...
   if (mcnt3 > 0)
   {
       break; 
   }
   ...
}
```

Comment: If i use break, it will cause the anbother problem like when the the codition flow from the initial it will automatically skip the statemens. I want break only after executing the methods in the loop. The loop may execute more times for next iteration..If i put break, the next iteration will affect before executing the required statements.

Comment: @user1466470: it would help if you could add more information on your question in relation to this. Honestly, I don't get the idea. You could use pseudocode to explain if that helps.

Comment: I have to write C# code for comparing the keys. If the values are changed i have to correct it by the default value.

Comment: The keys are HKEY_USER and H_KEY_CURRENT_USER

Comment: For this purpose, I have two method to find all the subkeys of each key. To find several keys i use foreach loop..First i set uservalue1..then  have to check whether the value and keyname is matched with the default value in HKEY_USER. My problem is the first value is checked with all the subkeys in 2nd key.. I want to break the second loop after finding the name and value that is matched with the first name and value.

Answer (score 0):

Sound like you need a `break;` where you want to loop your currently in to end.

However, you can also use `continue;` to stay in your current loop, but skipping to next iteration.

If you want it to break out of both for loops, you have to have a boolean variable inside the first loop (like `bool breakLoop = false;`), and set it to true before jumping your current loop, and place and if right after the for loop you broke out of and then call if breakLoop is true, call another break.